# Saving cycles when placing huge .png in a small space in WPF Reply Quote Edit

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hey. I have a listbox that shows 3000 by 3000 pixel images (at 96 dpi) in a 50 by 50 space. They're thumbnails. What is the most efficient way to do this? I ask because it seems like the listbox renders really slow.

It should be noted that I'm doing this in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness of your listbox is definitely related to the size of the assets placed in the listbox.

You need to create actual thumbnails and use them instead. On focus you can then get the actual required image to show.

Have a google and look at this on how to create thumbnails.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/thumbnail08072007131100PM/thumbnail.aspx

You probably want to save the thumbnails and not generate that on the fly.

Comment: I do not want to have to maintain two images, one large and one small. I will use the code example you have provided. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The 'maintenance' can be automated though. Every time you add a new image and save it, you then also generate the thumb and save it as well. When you delete the image, you delete the thumb, etc.